# Importing Arabic characters from a .CSV file to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have tried importing a CSV file which contains Arabic data "characters" to a MySQL database using PhpMyAdmin, but when I browse the table to which I imported, no data appear in the fields. The rows are empty, even though I have used the `Utf8_unicode_ci` encoding.

Why has this problem occurred, and how can I make Arabic characters appear in the table?

Note: when I insert Arabic characters in the table by hand, characters appear in the table but when I import them to the table nothing appears.

Comment: Are you sure the rows are empty in the database, or do they just appear to be empty when you browse in PhpMyAdmin? Are the characters there if you view the web page's source?

Comment: Is the CSV file UTF8 encoded?

Comment: when i  browsing the table in PhpMyAdmin it appear to be empty, since whe i select data from the table using MySQL console  it appears as question mark ( ???) as follow

mysql> use MYDB;
Database changed

mysql> select * from disease;
+------------+--------------+
| Disease_ID | name         |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | ?????        |
|          2 | ??????       |
|          3 | ?????        |
|          4 | ?????? ????? |
+------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

Comment: same problem with me

Answer (score -1):

try to import it to MS access first then export it using ODBC connection with Mysql